# Why my Wireless USB Network Card wont get off monitor mode and won't change channel?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, kali-linux

I am practicing Wireless Network Security and for this I need two main functionalities of my Wireless USB card: 1) TO be able to go into monitor mode, and 2) to be able to change channel according to what I want to do.

I am currently able to put my card into monitor mode but there is no way I can turn this off and connect back to the internet. I have to restart the computer. Why is this happening?

Additionally, when I use the command iwconfig wlan0mon channel x, after I have shut it down, the card will not obey and will randomly pick a channel each time I try to do i.g aireplay-ng. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

First of, to get your card out of monitor mode use `airomon-ng stop [card name(eg. Wlan0mon)]`
Also aireplay automatically changes channels though, there is an option which will keep it on one channel, just look through "aireplay-ng help"

Edit: if you're using Kali or debian you need to restart the networkmanager

Comment: The airmon-ng stop xxxx will stop the interface but I still can't get connected to the internet and need to restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command airmon-ng stop [network card] [channel] to stop monitor mode and change the channel of the network card.